# Using EJBs in thread spawned from Servlet - bad practice?

Tags: servlets, thread-safety, ejb-3.0

We have a servlet as follows:

```
public class CacheRefresher extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long START_TIMEOUT = 120*1000;

    public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
        super.init(servletConfig);
        new Thread(new Worker()).start();

    }

    private class Worker implements Runnable {
        public Worker() { }
        public void run() {   
            try {
                Thread.sleep(START_TIMEOUT);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            while(true) {
                MyService myService = null;
                try {
                    myService = ServiceFactory.getInstance().getMyService();
                    myService.doSomething();
                } catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    ServiceFactory.getInstance().releaseMyService(myService);
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(timeout);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Its purpose is to periodically call a service. There will only be a single instance of this Servlet, which will be created on server startup. MyService is an EJB.

How bad is this? I know spawning threads from EJBs is not allowed, but what about the other way around? What will happen on server shutdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptualy i dont see a problem with invoking ejb methods from multiple threads (even if you created the threads yourself). For the ejb-container that will be just another client among others.

From your example it looks like the soul purpose of you servlet is to start a bunch of timers. If you can use ejb 3.1, there is java ee standard way to do that.

First a Singleton ejb that launches the timers on startup

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;


@Singleton
@Startup
public class SingletonBean {

    @EJB
    LabBean labBean;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        long interval = 4000;
        long initialExpiration = 2000;
        labBean.startTimer(initialExpiration, interval, "MyTimer");
    }
}
```

Then a SLSB that handles the timeout:

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ejb.Timer;
import javax.ejb.TimerConfig;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;


@Stateless
public class LabBean {
    @Resource
    protected TimerService timerService;

    @Timeout
    public void timeoutHandler(Timer timer) {
        String name = timer.getInfo().toString();
        System.out.println("Timer name=" + name);
    }

    public void stopTimer(String name) {
        for (Object o : this.timerService.getTimers())
            if (((Timer) o).getInfo().toString().startsWith(name)){
                ((Timer)o).cancel();
            }       
    }

    public void startTimer(long initialExpiration, long interval, String name){
        stopTimer(name);        
        TimerConfig config = new TimerConfig();
        config.setInfo(name);
        config.setPersistent(false);
        timerService.createIntervalTimer(initialExpiration, interval, config);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know of the timers of EJB 3.1 and use them in other projects, this is sadly ejb 3.1 though. Thanks for the answer still.